# Display all b tags inside p tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, django, beautifulsoup

I have app in django and I have to display text in specific way.

This is my html code:

```
<p class="name">
<b>Name of person</b> City, Country</p>
<p class="name">
<b>Name of person</b></p>
```

I want to get bolded Name of person and City and Country in normal text, for example:

```
**Name of person** City, Country
**Name of person**
```

But I can get only b, how can I get all p and b inside p?

My code in BeautifulSoap:

```
people = self.concattexts.filter(code='Active')
for p in people:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(p.text_html, 'html.parser')
    all_people = [b.get_text(separator=' - ', strip=True) for b in soup.find_all('b')]
    return all_people
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = '''
<p class="name">
<b>Name of person</b> City, Country</p>
<p class="name">
<b>Name of person</b></p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc,'lxml')

for i in soup.find_all('p', class_='name'):
    print(i.get_text(separator=' - ', strip=True))
```

out:

```
Name of person - City, Country
Name of person
```

`get_text()` can get all the text below the tag, there is no need to use `b tag`, just `p tag` will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Text without a tag is a `NavigableString`:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<p class="name"><b>Name of person</b> City, Country</p>',
...                      'html.parser')
>>> children = list(soup.p.children)
>>> children
[<b>Name of person</b>, u' City, Country']
>>> type(children[-1])
<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
>>> isinstance(children[-1], basestring)
True
```

I suggest getting the children of `p` and making sure that they have the right structure (a `<b>` tag followed by a string) and then extract the information as you wish.